# "The DevTools has been shut out. It will automatically reconnect to DevTool once you reload the page."

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a very simple tool for a company, it's an aide to help visualize rail cuts.
I use a simple HTML page to build a display and then use JS to perform the simulated cuts and visualize them.

I have the file shared with some people via a shared drive. People in the US seem to be able to use the file without issue.

Someone in Europe tried to use the file and was able to open the file, but nothing happens upon trying to run the page's script, and when f12 is pressed, they receive the message in the title (their system is in Japanese locale I believe, so it is roughly translated).

They do not have this problem if they save the file locally and run it from there, only when using it from the shared folder.

Running the file content through https://validator.w3.org/ yields no problems or errors.
It works for me and most others I have asked to try the tool.

Let me know if additional info is needed. I'd like to try avoid sharing code if possible because the company will get mad if I share the proprietary code I made but I can if I need to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032227/tips-on-solving-devtools-was-disconnected-from-the-page-and-electron-helper-di has someone in a similar scenario.

Comment: I did find that question, but it doesn't seem relevant to my scenario. I'm just using standard JS, tested in chrome, no Electron, NPM, etc. It works fine for me but not someone on another PC